# CodingBat AP-1, task no. 4?

Tags: java, arrays, average

I have some problems with CodingBat's "scoresAverage" task, in the category AP-1. The task says the following:

> Given an array of scores, compute the int average of the first half and the second half, and return whichever is larger. We'll say that the second half begins at index length/2. The array length will be at least 2. To practice decomposition, write a separate helper method 
> int average(int[] scores, int start, int end) { which computes the average of the elements between indexes start..end. Call your helper method twice to implement scoresAverage(). Write your helper method after your scoresAverage() method in the JavaBat text area. Normally you would compute averages with doubles, but here we use ints so the expected results are exact.

Okay, so following the rules, I wrote a code with decomposition, but for some mysterious reason it  doesn't work 100% properly. Here is my code:

```
public int scoresAverage(int[] scores) {
    int startFirst=0;
    int endFirst=scores.length/2;
    
    int startSecond=scores.length/2;
    int endSecond=scores.length;
    
    int a=average(scores,startFirst,endFirst);
    int b=average(scores,startSecond,endSecond);
    
    int avg = Math.max(a,b);
    return avg;
}

public int average(int[] scores, int start, int end) {
    int count=0;
    for (int i=start;i<end;i++){
        count+=scores[i];
    }
    return count/end;
}
```

The output goes fine with some of the tests, but not for the others and I can't see the reason why! You can test my code on CodingBat yourselves: http://codingbat.com/prob/p123837

Please don't write me totally different codes unless my one is really useless! I know there must be millions of ways to solve this problem, and I also think that mine is not one of the best ones (i'm quite a noob) but still I want to know what the problem with MY code is in the first place. Better/simpler alternatives are very much welcome, though.

Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is when you actually compute the average from the length. Here's how I did it; don't feel pressured to use it...

```
int average( int[] scores, int start, int end ) {
  int sum = 0;
  for ( int i = start; i < end; ++i ) {
    sum += scores[i];
  }
  return ( sum / ( end - start ) );
}
```

As you can tell yours -> `return count/end;`
and mine differ.

In case you're interested, you can make your code a bit more concise like so...

```
public int scoresAverage(int[] scores) {
  int a1 = average( scores, 0, scores.length / 2 );
  int a2 = average( scores, scores.length / 2, scores.length );
  return ( a1 > a2 ) ? a1 : a2;
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you! :) I assume the problem was with the second call, where the parameter _end_ was actually the total length of the array, including the first part of the array which should not have been included... How could I have missed this???

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Mistakes happen to everyone; don't worry about it.